# FullCalendar - Prevent reloading of events from JSON source on month change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

Is there a way to prevent FullCalendar from re-fetching events from a JSON source when you change month?

The JSON source provides the initial list of events which can then be edited on the client side using: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` However changing month causes the events to be reloaded from the server, replacing the changed events with the original values.

I've tried setting `stick` to true in the event data from the JSON source, I've also tried setting `cache` to true when adding the event data source. I've left `lazyFetching` as true.

I guess a workaround would be to retrieve the JSON and add this as an array data source rather than a JSON data source..

Comment: Are your events from a database? When your events are changed why not update them?

Comment: They are, but the underlying data shouldn't be updated until the user is happy / all the events on the calendar have passed validation.

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't a way to prevent refetching.
lazyFetch is for a smaller scope on the data that already cached (changing the view from month to week - the data is already in the client).

I'm not sure what you are trying to do.
how do you save changes when the user is happy?

I think the best practice in that case is to have a list of changes that uses both for a final approval when the user is happy and for re-rendering the calendar after the calendar re-fetch events when navigating.

add a listener to the refetch events and then change the events that the user changed earlier.